# Bootstrap theme not as wide as parent container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need help with bootstrap container and row width.

I have created a container and a row inside it. I have everything inside the row, but for some reason content sizes are different as displayed on jsfiddle and image preview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
    <head>
        <title>xGhost.cz | Československý Gamehosting.</title>
        <!-- meta data -->
        <meta name="author" content="Jan Dvořák">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP START -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP END -->      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-lg">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <img src="img/xGhost.svg" alt="" style="width: 300px; height: auto;"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mt-2">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="font-style: italic;">xGhost.cz</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Úvod</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Ceník</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Objednávka</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Příručka</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Servery</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Technika</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="row gx-2 mt-3">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-heading">Novinky & Blog</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-heading">Přihlášení</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.navbar {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(39, 174, 96, 1.0) !important;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.box-heading {
    background: #212529 !important;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1c9w3taq/

[Image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OrJb.jpg)

On the image you can clearly see, where the spaces are. It all should be aligned from side to side inside the container. Logo column width is missing a few pixels on the right and the two boxes in the bottom are not touching the sides of parrent container.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from this div.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
```

as well as  `<div class="col-md-4">`

Yes they both equal 12 but they contain a margin.

To fix this you can add a class like this.

```
.nomargin{
margin: 0px !important;
}
```

And use the class like this

This will remove the default bootstrap margin.

Comment: It did not work. I created .nomargin in my css file and added the class to those columns col-md-4 and col-md-8, but they still look the same.

col-md-8 is a bit moved to the right, a few pixels from its left side as on image and col-md-4 is not really on the right side, there are a few pixels left on the right side.

Comment: You may still be running into problems then due to Boostrap being able to organise it's own margins. No CSS of any kind is needed and so in creating it and trying to add it Bootstrap might be in confusion. I recommend using the standard methods of paddings and margins some of which is already in use in your code and which is all here... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/